# how to separate some parts of three20 library

Tags: iphone, three20

i need to have a ThumbsViewController and i used three20(TTThumbsViewController) library to accomplish this task, the question is, can i separate just this part of three20 library and use in my project instead of adding reference to three20 library

thanks in advance

Comment: If I were you, I won't use three20, it's too bulky and not nicely implemented. I would read the code and learn how stuff works, then write my own.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using only the photo viewer from three20, you better off using a different solution.

Try [KTPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser). It has the same functionally of three20 photo viewer, while also looks to be very lightweight.